# Getting OleDb.OleDbException querying MSAccess ACCDB with F# SQL TypeProvdier

Tags: f#, oledb, type-providers

I am trying to write a provider for MSAccess, for the fsprojects/SQLProvider  Type Provider (https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider). The type alias is defined thus

```
type mdb = SqlDataProvider< @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\Temp\\BT.accdb", Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSACCESS>
```

pointing to a .accdb file in c:\temp. This works fine, if there are no joins in the query, eg.:

```
let data = query {
                for epi in mdbctx.``[BT].[Episodes]`` do
                where (epi.Urgent = true)
                select epi.LabNumber
                }
```

But if there is a join

```
    let data = query {
                for epi in mdbctx.``[BT].[Episodes]`` do
                join eu in mdbctx.``[BT].[EpisodeUnits]`` on (epi.ID = eu.EpisodeID)
                where (epi.Urgent = true)
                select epi.LabNumber
                }
```

OledDb throws an error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find file 'C:\Users\BLYNCH\AppData\Local\Temp\BT.mdb'.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.QueryImplementation.executeQuery(String conString, ISqlProvider provider, SqlExp sqlExp, List`1 ti) in C:\code_root\SQLProvider\src\SQLProvider\SqlRuntime.Linq.fs:line 38
at FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.QueryImplementation.SqlQueryable`1.System-Collections-Generic-IEnumerable`1-GetEnumerator() in C:\code_root\SQLProvider\src\SQLProvider\SqlRuntime.Linq.fs:line 71
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Complaining about an MDB file, in a completely different place to the connection string! If I put a MDB copy of the ACCDB in the location, then the code runs without issue.

Any OleDb experts out there have any idea why it is looking there in the first place, and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

For me joins worked using the Jet OLEDB provider: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"